# VBA Import MS Access to MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have a VBA module in MS-Access that is supposed to load data from a database into Form Fields in a MS-Word document.  I thought it was working fine, but it appears to be inconsistent.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  I can't figure out what keeps it from working.  When I step through the debugger it doesn't throw any errors, but sometimes it doesn't open MS-Word.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
'Avoid error 429, when Word isn't open.
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear

'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.
Set appWord = New Word.Application
End If

Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("\\srifs01\hresourc\EHS Department\EHS Database\IpadUpload\Lab Inspection Deficiency Resolution Report.docx", , True)

'Sometimes word doesn't open and I think the issue is around here.
With doc
.FormFields("frmID").Result = Me!id
.FormFields("frmSupervisor").Result = Me!LabPOC
.FormFields("frmInspector").Result = Me!InspectorName
.FormFields("frmBuilding").Result = Me!BuildingName
.FormFields("frmRoom").Result = Me!Rooms
.FormFields("frmComments").Result = Me!Comments
.Visible = True
.Activate
.SaveAs "'" & Me!id & "'"
.Close
End With

Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are getting?

Comment: There is no error message.  Sometimes it just doesn't work.  It steps through but does nothing.  I think its because its not opening MS-Word.

Comment: You do not seem to be closing Word. (appWord.Quit) Are you showing copies in Task Manager?

Comment: Im closing word within the `With doc .Close`

Comment: You are closing the document, you are not necessarily closing Word.

Comment: You right.  I just checked task manager and word was running, but after I closed it and ran the code again it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"When I step through the debugger it doesn't throw any errors, but sometimes it doesn't open MS-Word."*

That's because you have `On Error Resume Next`.  That instructs VBA to ignore errors.

Assume you've made this change in your code ...

```
Dim strDocPath As String
strDocPath = "\\srifs01\hresourc\EHS Department\EHS Database" & _
    "\IpadUpload\Lab Inspection Deficiency Resolution Report.docx"
```

Then, when you attempt to open `strDocPath`, VBA would throw an error if `appWord` isn't a reference to a Word application instance ... **AND** you haven't used `On Error Resume Next`:

```
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(strDocPath, , True)
```

You can get rid of `On Error Resume Next` if you change your assignment for `appWord` to this:

```
Set appWord = GiveMeAnApp("Word.Application")
```

If Word was already running, `GiveMeAnApp()` would latch onto that application instance.  And if Word was not running, `GiveMeAnApp()` would return a new instance.

Either way, `GiveMeAnApp()` doesn't require you to use `On Error Resume Next` in your procedure which calls it.  Include a proper error handler there instead.  And you can reuse the function for other types of applications: `GiveMeAnApp("Excel.Application")`

```
Public Function GiveMeAnApp(ByVal pApp As String) As Object
    Dim objApp As Object
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set objApp = GetObject(, pApp)

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set GiveMeAnApp = objApp
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 429 ' ActiveX component can't create object
        Set objApp = CreateObject(pApp)
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
            & ") in procedure GiveMeAnApp"
        MsgBox strMsg
        GoTo ExitHere
    End Select
End Function
```

You could also include a check to make sure `appWord` references an application before you attempt to use it.  Although I don't see why such a check should be necessary in your case, you can try something like this ...

```
If TypeName(appWord) <> "Application" Then
    ' notify user here, and bail out '
Else
    ' appWord.Visible = True '
    ' do stuff with Word '
End If
```

Comment: I guess its better this way.  But it still doesn't open up the MS-Word, and it still doesn't throw an error.

Comment: I don't understand how it fails to give you a Word instance without throwing an error.  (Do you perhaps have `SetWarnings = False`?  That can be risky by suppressing information, but I wouldn't suspect it here.)  I added an update to check that `appWord` is an application reference.  See if that helps.

Comment: Upon closer inspection it looks likes its opening an instance of word in the processes, but I don't actually visually see it open.  It also doesn't import the MS-Access data into it or save it as a new file.

Comment: Document `.SaveAs` with full path to the file you want created.  (Crap!  Your last question disappeared.)

Comment: Yeah, I answered my own question.  I guess I should have left it for future reference.  The question was "How do I save to particular folder rather than My Documents?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the `New` keyword when opening or finding an application.

This is the code I use for excel:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then 'Excel not running
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

(note also the `On Error GoTo 0` - I don't want the resume next to be active all through the code)

Comment: @talbright GetObject works to return a running instance of Word. I quite like New, but if you are using it, you don't use getobject, if you are using getobject, you need all the code shown above. I would also make sure my instance was visible.

Comment: When I use the above code `Set appWord = CreateObject(, "Word.Application")`  It throws me a compile error.

Comment: CreateObject takes the name of the object as the first parameter - get object uses the second parameter. remove the comma, and it should work

Answer (score 0):

The GiveMeAnApp function worked great for me with a similar problem I was experiencing. Except, to avoid Error 462 (cannot connect to server etc) if I closed the Word document after the data merge and attempted another merge of data to Word. (which caused error 462) I did this: Once I call GiveMeAnApp I then called for a New Word document before calling the Word template I wished to transfer data to Word into.

By always having the New Word document present this avoided error 462 in my circumstances. It means I am left with an empty Word doc but this is ok for me and preferable to the only other solution I could come up with which was to quit the db and re open and run the merge to Word aga.

I am grateful for the help set out in this thread. Thanks all.